# What are the black canisters mounted low on power poles?

Tags: identification

I understood the low, fat black cable to be data cable, strung low because it isn't a severe electrical hazard. Recently I noticed a lot of these near my property **in Australia** on the other side of the planet from the alleged duplicate, governed by totally different engineering constraints and electrical and telecommunication regulations.

[image: canister on pole]

I would have thought them to be junction boxes but the runs are very short. Can anyone positively identify them?

On some of the poles there is *only* the fat black cable so I speculate that they are fibre joins. The junction box idea was inspired by the fact that in some cases there are three or sometimes four cables entering the enclosure.

What confuses me is that in some cases they are only two poles apart. I would have imagined it cheaper to discard a bit of fibre than install and maintain another whatsit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are pole mounted weather-proof housings for telecom equipment. They could have different things inside but one use is for T1 repeaters which are placed at intervals along the line to boost and clean up the signals that have been degraded by cable losses. The housings are cylindrical because they can be pressurized to keep out moisture.

Here's the [datasheet](https://www.charlesindustries.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/LTAC4-306-003.pdf) for one such device. It states that they can be either pressurized or vented, and recommend that pressurized ones only be used in underground installations.

Comment: Why are they pressurized instead of sealed (maybe with some desiccant inside)?

Comment: @Michael seals eventually fail, and you won't notice until it is too late. A pressure sensor inside can tell you how well they are doing.

Comment: @Davidmh: But pressurized requires seals as well? And a humidity or a simple water sensor inside can tell you if a merely waterproof seal is failing too.

Comment: @Michael a humidity sensor tells you when the seal has failed, it rains, _and the water is inside_. A pressure sensor can tell you as soon as the seal is starting to fail -- hopefully while the technician is still up there --, and if it fails slowly, gives you some time to fix it.

Comment: @Michael A desicant only works once the moisture is already in the container, can only remove so much moisture at a time, and has to be changed regularly. Also, there would be normal air inside the container which can support oxidation. By pressurizing with nitrogen you make it very difficult for any moisture to get in at all, you have a relatively inert atmosphere, and it probably doesn't need to be serviced anywhere near as often.

Comment: @Michael O-rings work best with a pressure differential that doesn't change polarity. Sealing the unit at atmospheric pressure will cause an o-ring to move back & forth as the canister goes from positive to negative pressure due to temperature swings. This motion can cause o-ring failure over time. By pressurizing the canister, the o-ring position will not change.

Comment: There is an underground pressurized conduit next to my house.  Every time it rains, a puddle forms on the ground and bubbles come up through it.  The gurgling noise is audible from 20 feet away.  AT&T repaired it a few months ago but now it's leaking again and they don't seem to care any more.

Comment: @Michael It is surprising how different fields and different countries come up with wildly different solutions to identical problems. The reasons given here may all be true but they are not compelling: I have not seen such a thing in my life in Germany, we somehow manage to keep water out by other means. But then we don't dangle our lines from trees and poles that much to begin with, even though we have far fewer hurricanes and wildfires.

Comment: I've edited my answer a bit reguarding pressurization and included a link to a datasheet.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Different parts of the US handle it differently - some regions hang, some regions bury.